# Making a <DIV> go under another <DIV> when no space

Tags: html, css

So I have two `<div>` next to each other and I want to make it so when you have little space (Phone for example) it puts the second `<div>` under the first one with some space. When you're on a 16:9 ratio computer it has them next to each other.

```css
body {
  background: #FFFFFF;
}
.box {
  float: left;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 25px;
  max-width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
div {
  max-width: 2480px;
  z-index: 2;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  top: 0px;
  color: #2D2E32;
  background: #2D2E32;
}
/*Box1*/

div2 {
  position: absolute;
  color: #2D2E32;
  background: #2D2E32;
  width: 700px;
  height: 950px;
  top: 700;
  left: 200;
}
div3
/*Box2*/

{
  position: absolute;
  color: #2D2E32;
  background: #2D2E32;
  width: 700px;
  height: 950px;
  top: 700;
  right: 10%;
}
img {
  max-height: 800;
  max-width: 2480;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 100%;
  height: 63%;
  left: 10%;
}
div4 {
  max-height: 59%;
  z-index: -1;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 59%;
  top: 5%;
  color: #17181A;
  background: #17181A;
  left: 0;
}
div5 {
  max-width: 2480;
  max-height: 25;
  z-index: 2;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 25px;
  color: #2D2E32;
  background: #2D2E32;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="page1">
    <!--Task-->
    <a id="Task" class="smooth"></a>
  </div>
  <div2 id="page2">
    <!--Box1-->
    <a id="Info1" class="smooth" class="box"></a>
  </div2>
  <div3>
    <!--Box2-->
    <a id="Info1" class="smooth" class="box"></a>
  </div3>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[CSS Media Queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries)** will solve this problem by allowing you to create styles that will be conditionally applied based on a query that you specify.  Here's an example:

```css
/* Develop "mobile-first, meaning that your normal styles should reflect how you want
   the content to look on a mobile device
 
   div elements will normally appear on their own line, but let's add a little space between 
   the lines
*/

div { margin:1em; }



/* When the viewport is not bigger than 760px and it is rotated to be wide 
   put divs next to each other and only move them down when the full width 
   of the viewport is used up */
@media screen and (max-width:760px) and (orientation:landscape) {
  div {
    float:left;
    margin:auto; /* reset margins back to normal */
  }
}
```

```html
<div>Some div content</div>
<div>Some div content</div>
```